# Ошибка алгоритма отображения элементов

Tags: jquery, циклы, javascript

Почему не отображает 2 последних элемента? :(

forum_icon - выводит 31 элемент, а на деле почему-то 27...

```
var forum_icon = $(this).find('.forumIcoTd img').map(function () {
    return $(this).attr('src');
}).get();

var i = 0;
var groupEl = [];
for (i; i < forum_icon.length; i++) {
    var f_icon = forum_icon[i];

    var f_tmpl = 'тут контент';
    groupEl.push(f_tmpl);
}
$('#new_forum').append(groupEl.join(''));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тяжело что-то сказать без теста.
Но, думаю, что проблема в самом начале, и в масив попадают не все элементы img.

```
$(this).find('.forumIcoTd img')
```

Comment: @Iranda, и как быть?

Comment: Закиньте код в онлайн песочницу, и посмотрим что не так.

Comment: @markuper, вот как бы http://jsfiddle.net/Rg4gT/3/, но там форум и поэтому я выложил вкратце, чтобы было понятно.

Comment: Тяжело что то понять в коде, он не работает.
Опишите что вы хотите сделать, или дайте линк на рабочую копию!

Comment: @markuper, асю, скайп Ваш можно?

Comment: 497 191 пять девять восемь